# Как байпасить несколько слайдов капчи используя selenium и twocaptcha?

Tags: python, selenium

Столкнулся с проблемой, при отправки запроса к api сервиса TwoCaptcha

```
# Создание экземпляра класса TwoCaptcha для дальнейшей работы с байпасингом капчи
solver = TwoCaptcha(token)

# Получение sitekey
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')
src = iframe.get_attribute('src')
sitekey = src.split('k=')[1].split('&')[0]

# Использование библиотеки twocaptcha для решения reCAPTCHA
result = TwoCaptcha_solver.recaptcha(sitekey=sitekey, url=url)
captcha_solution = result['code']
```

Статус результата рабочий, ключ присылает, баланса хватает, работало все на страницы с предоставления https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

На произвольной же странице все иначе. Проведя небольшой анализ - пришел к выводу, что проблема возможно в нескольких слайдов капчи. Обратился к гуглу, сократил количество слайдов "очеловечив" автоматизацию (добавил произвольные задержки, сделал постепенный ввод текста, нажатие кнопок). Таким образом добился двух слайдов капчи. Капча не решается все равно.

Такой код использую для вставки решения капчи:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML=" + "'" + captcha_solution + "'")
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь в решении проблемы!